# Unable to redirect output in FreeBsd

Tags: bash, freebsd

On Freebsd system I run my bash script with an attempt to redirect output:

```
% sudo bash some_file.sh arg1 >/dev/null  2>&1
Ambiguous output redirect.


% sudo bash some_file.sh arg1 &> /dev/null
Invalid null command.
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you use csh on your command line (check with `echo $SHELL`).

- Either use the csh syntax to redirect both stdout and stderr would be: `sudo bash some_file.sh arg1 >& /dev/null`
- Or move the redirection into the "bash part" of the command with `sudo bash -c 'some_file.sh arg1 >/dev/null  2>&1'`

Answer (score 2):

You came close, but neither of those is the right syntax for the TENEX C shell.

Remember: The interactive login shell that you are using on FreeBSD, unless you have changed it, is the TENEX C shell.  Your redirection of the `sudo` command has to use the redirection syntax of the TENEX C shell.  It does not matter that you are running the Bourne Again shell via `sudo`.  That is only determined *after the redirection has taken place and `sudo` has already been run*.

This:

```
% sudo bash some_file.sh arg1 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

is effectively the same as

```
% >/dev/null >&1 sudo bash some_file.sh arg1 2
```

which attempts to redirect standard output twice to two different places.

This:

```
% sudo bash some_file.sh arg1 &> /dev/null
```

is actually

```
% sudo bash some_file.sh arg1 & > /dev/null
```

and will be rewritten as such in your command history.  It is two commands joined by `&`, `sudo` and a command with no name nor arguments.  The latter is not allowed in the TENEX C shell.

This is how to redirect both standard output and standard error to `/dev/null` in the TENEX C shell:

```
% sudo bash some_file.sh arg1 >& /dev/null
```

Comment: is it because of freebsd? even so I'm using "bash"?

Comment: is it because of freebsd? even so I'm using "bash"?